# Laravel - listado de items refrescar datos con ajax?

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, laravel-blade, blade

Tengo un proyecto que el backend es laravel (API) y tengo un sencillo frontal con el motor de plantilla blade.

Tengo un listado de coches y el usuario tiene un botón que los puede habilitar y deshabilitar.

Ahora mismo con jquery lo que hago es hacer una llamada "put" para actualizar el estado de dicho elemento (coche) y para refrescar la información lo hago con jquery.

```
    $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){

    var id_site_promocion = $("input[name=id_site_promocion]").val();
    var activo = $("input[name=activo]").val();
    $('.btn-submit').prop('disabled', true);
    e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({

        type:'PUT',
        url:'/api/coches/' + id_site_promocion ,
        data: {
            activo : activo,
        },
        success:function(data){
            //ok

        },
        error:function (data) {
            //error
        }
    });

});
```

Para un elemento no me parece "engorroso" pero si fuera más de un elemento? Lo harias así o harias una llamada AJAX con GET y refrescarías la tabla?

Tengo la misma duda para hacer un GRID de elementos donde puedas editar "inline" un elemento y guardar esos cambios, construyo un form por cada elemento y el botón de cada form que sea un submit?

Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Yo no me complicaría la vida, yo lo que hago siempre después de actualizar algún dato es refrescar la tabla entera volviendo a cargar los datos via AJAX. aunque sean muchos datos, el tiempo de carga son milisegundos, así que tampoco notas mucha diferencia.

En resumidas cuentas, en el success pones un "reload" de la tabla y listo.

Comment: Gracias @Ferran Muñoz, mi intención es que no se "note" el efecto de recargo de página, haciendo esto que dices no se notaria? Algun link de ejemplo? Gracias

Comment: Ahora que leo otra vez tu primer post... Veo que es un formulario. En tu caso no hace falta que refresques nada en el success, en tu caso haría un mensaje en forma de alert o toast informando que el cambio se ha hecho correctamente y ya está, no hace falta recargar la página. Y en caso que sea grid/tabla, hazla mediante datatable (de jquery), carga los datos via ajax y al success refrescas la tabla mediante nombretabla.reload(); Y esto si, son milisegundos, no sale ni el circulo de carga ni nada.